# Inline translation: slowing magento down and other pros and cons?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, localisation, inline-translations

I like to do my custom translations using the inline translation tool in M2.1.

My questions are:

- What, in general, are the downsides of this method?
- Are there any pros (apart from that the method is easy to use from the backend)?
- Is this method slowing down the frontend loading time?
- If so, does it slow the website down considerately?
- Does this method add code to the page source that negatively affects SEO?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

`Magento\Framework\Translate::loadData($area = null, $forceReload = false)`

```
   if (!$forceReload) {
        $this->_data = $this->_loadCache();
        if ($this->_data !== false) {
            return $this;
        }
    }
    $this->_data = [];

    $this->_loadModuleTranslation();
    $this->_loadThemeTranslation();
    $this->_loadPackTranslation();
    $this->_loadDbTranslation();

    if (!$forceReload) {
        $this->_saveCache();
    }
```

As we can see, the `$this->_loadDbTranslation()` translate inline will be loaded at the last. It will be overridden all. So, your Magento will be slow down.

> Inline translation: slowing Magento down

However, Magento will load the translation from cache, so, the inline translation will make your Magento is slow at the first time. I think that helps Magento translation is faster for all cases.

Why doesn't inline translation encourage?

- Hard to find the translation, we need to find in the database. And, need to enable this functionality. It takes more time.
- Slow

**[Need to check more cases]**

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Exactly the explanation I was hoping for. One more question: would it be possible to tell how much the extra loading time would be, more or less?